# Laravel - Get values from pivot table column, using pivot tables unique row ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to figure out if there's some way to get the values of two columns in a pivot table, based on a unique incrementing ID that I gave each row.

I have a Job model, a Location model, and an Application model.

The Job and Location have a many to many relationship with a pivot table "job_location". The two foreign keys it contains are job_id and location_id. However, I also gave every row a unique incrementing ID, jobloc_id.

If I only have the jobloc_id, how can I look up the values of the other two columns?

```
 $jobLoc = $location->jobs->wherePivot('jobloc_id', '=', 1);
 return $jobLoc->job_id;
```

Returns "Method wherePivot does not exist" even though I've seen references of people using it. All I have is the jobloc_id, and am trying to lookup the other two values based on this so that I can fully load the Job and Location to pull attributes from them.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. This is in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Pivot tables aren't meant to have an ID column, you're probably trying to do something that you shouldn't.

Comment: In database theory, pivot tables don't has ID columns as @AntoineB said,
Instead their primary key is the combination of both relation participants.
There are two odd solutions you can use, elevate the relation between Job & Location to entity and have two N-1 relation on it, one with Job & the another with Location.

Or simply use Laravel Query Builder

Comment: @AntoineB There's nothing wrong with having a unique ID column on a pivot table. It's not required but it can be useful. Multiple guides I've gone through have said they still add one to it. I'm essentially trying to access the combination of the job<->location with one number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're added ID to pivot table (`jobloc_id` for example) and you want to get row by ID, just use query builder:

```
DB::table('job_location')->where('jobloc_id', 1)->first();
```

That's the fastest and simpliest way to do that when you have unique row ID in the pivot table.

Comment: Tried this and it worked. Ended up making a model just for the pivot table however, and which is giving me a little more control.